# Galois theory for real algebraic sets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,
is there a "Galois" theory for rational functions of real algebraic sets
similiar to the one relating coverings of riemanien surfaces with Galois Extension of
meromofphic functions?

Thanks